# Swift 2/Cocoa: Good practice for large item collections and their impending UI updates

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I am doing a lookup-type app with about 800 JSON entries total, which I'm able to load into memory fine because I'm just parsing plaintext into some objects to act as simple Models.

However, I don't know what the best practice is to deal with the UI end of that, which is where things slow down immensely trying to scroll, etc:

[image]

So I tried implementing pagination with the numbered buttons, which works but the UI still locks up updating and the pages collide for a split second while the `NSCollectionView` updates.

[image]

Here is the code that currently causes the initial and page loads to happen in `ViewController.swift`:

The action that clicking the buttons cause

```
@IBAction func changePage(sender: NSButton) {
    let newPage = Int(sender.title)
    currentPageNumber = newPage!
}

public let pageSize = 200;

public var currentPageNumber : Int{
    didSet{
        if(fullMorphemesList.count == 0){
            return;
        }
        loadMorphemesByPage(currentPageNumber)
    }
}
```

The logic where the items are being loaded in:

```
///Load morphemes based on page number
func loadMorphemesByPage(pageNumber : Int){
    let beginIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
    let endIndex = pageNumber * pageSize

    loadMorphemesIntoDisplay(from: beginIndex, to: endIndex)
}

///Loads morphemes into the collection view
public func loadMorphemesIntoDisplay(from index: Int, to endIndex: Int){
    let morphemesToLoad = fullMorphemesList[index..<endIndex]
    collectionView.content = (Array(morphemesToLoad) as [AnyObject])
}
```

Hopefully the code makes sense since I put them in approximate firing order. Are there extra steps I'm missing out on? Are there async UI methods I could use to not lock up the rest of the UI, and have the list update in the correct order without visual artifacts?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It is hard to say what can cause slowness, there may be tons of reasons. But getting 200 objects to collection view should not be that slow. To find the reason for artifacts I would start playing with CA Layers of different view. Start with backing everything with CA Layers (in Utilities View of XCode - the last item with embedded squares icons, check Core Animation Layer for collection view parent and children). See if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an NSTableView for the scrollable list of morphemes instead and implement the data source/delegate methods (Don't forget the reuseIdentifier for the table cell). NSCollectionView also allows supports lazy loading with the data source/delegates but has proven to be heavier in such cases. You can get even more scrolling performance improvements by turning on layers and setting your NSTableRowView's canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer as yes.

So basically:

1. Create your NSTableCellView subclass and xib (again don't forget the reuse identifier).
2. Register your xib with your view-based NSTableView and use the reuseIdentifier inside

`func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSView`